# Projecting AK, HI, PR on US Map in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a default map for SAS that projects states like AK,HI, and PR in a more US-centric manner without the need for code workarounds as seen in [this](http://support.sas.com/kb/42/426.html).

Alternatively, is there a simpler way to perform this than in the link provided above?  Seems like a lot of code for what would seem to be a relatively common task...

The output I'm looking for would be something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Have you already checked robslink.com? It's down but he usually has a few ways.

Comment: I presume you have to get it done in base SAS? Or do you have access to Visual anaytics?

Comment: @Reeza Yes I've been slowly making my way through them but sometimes it's like searching for a needle in a haystack - there's so many examples.

Comment: @PythonRSAS I don't have access to VA unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found one...

```
proc gmap data=mapsgfk.us map=mapsgfk.us ; 
  id statecode; 
  choro segment / levels=1 nolegend coutline=gray99 des='' name="blah"; 
run;
```

Produces the below image.  It's missing PR but I can get by with this for the time being.

[image]

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? SGMAP is a bit experimental still but it's much better quality graphics IMO.

Comment: @Reeza SAS 9.4ts1m5.  Always down for better looking results =)

Comment: I like this post, shows a lot of what's possible now, nice to not have to drop down to ArcGIS for these.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2018/11/29/proc-sgmap-series-plot-importing-shapefiles-and-using-proc-gproject/